# como cambiar imagen de perfil y borrar la antigua en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, imagen

estoy aprendiendo laravel y estoy haciendo un panel de usuario donde este tiene un avatar por defecto, el usuario puede cambiar su imagen de perfil, ya logre subir la imagen y desplegarla, el problema es que cada vez que subo una imagen nueva, la vieja sigue en el directorio, como hago para que en el directorio solo quede la imagen que subo (sin borrar el avatar por defecto)

public function update(Request $r){

```
  if ($r->hasFile('img')) {

    $file = $r->file('img');
    $filename = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = 'avatar';
    $file->move($path, $filename);
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    DB::table('users')->where('id', $user_id)->update(['img' => $filename]);
     }
    Session::flash('success', 'Profile updated.');
    return redirect('profile/'.Auth::user()->name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de otra manera con File

```
// Delete a single file
File::delete($filename);
// Delete multiple files
File::delete($file1, $file2, $file3);
// Delete an array of files
$files = array($file1, $file2);
File::delete($files);
```

O tb puedes con el Storage

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);

Storage::delete('file.jpg');
Storage::delete(['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg']);
```

[Laravel Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: muchisimas gracias ya lo revisare para ver como funciona, saludos